# How can i show degree of expression in UILabel? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel

I have a label which shows an expression:

> (x+y)

But I want to show it in label like this:

> (x+y)^2

(But with degree, I can't do it here, because I have too low reputation to insert images)

So, I want to show expression's degree in UIlabel.
Is it possible with single UILabel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Unicode characters of superscript two `\u00B2`, it it's always `\u` followed by the character code.

```
NSString *equation = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(x+y)%@", @"\u00B2"];
```

Swift:

```
var equation = NSString(format:"(x+y)%@",  "\u{00B2}") as String
```

Result:

[image: Unicode]

http://unicode-table.com/en/

[Strings and Characters](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html) (Apple iOS Developer Library )

[Strings in Swift](http://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-strings/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for powers e.g. (x + y)⁹.
For this, You have to use unicodes.

you can take list of unicodes character list from here;
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/No/list.htm

In code, you will use;

```
print("(x+y)\u{00B2}");
```